# Make transitions in CSS rotations turn the shortest distance

Tags: javascript, css

I have a large wheel of div's which I rotate. I use CSS transitions to make it's movement look nice. I want to be able to set it's angle arbitrarily with JavaScript.

The problem I get is that if the angle is at zero, and I want to turn it to 270, it will turn all the way clockwise to 270. I would like for it to be "smart" and know that it is shorter to turn counterclockwise 90 degrees.

So aside from using JavaScript to calculate the proper rotation (The complexity of doing this in my situation is prohibitive) is there any way to make it "smart" about turning?

EDIT: I think I have seen something like this before, something built into CSS, but I can't seem to find it anywhere.

Comment: Unfortunately, in order for it to be smart, you must make it smart

Comment: this does not sound very complicated, if target rotation - current roation > 180, go the other way, in your example to -90 degrees... or am i missing something?

Comment: It becomes complicated, given the situation. I'm sure I saw something like this before at some point. Something built into CSS.

Comment: I can only think of one way to solve this. And it is to make some JavaScript calculating. This should then say, that if the value is over 180, it should take the value minus 180 and then minus this to 0. Then you would get the negative value.

Comment: I guess you should post that as an answer. I thought there was a way with just CSS though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would appear that the only way is with JavaScript, as Daniel commented:

> I can only think of one way to solve this. And it is to make some JavaScript calculating. 
>   This should then say, that if the value is over 180, it should take the value minus 180 and?> then minus this to 0. Then you would get the negative value.

Comment: @Daniel if you post this as an actual answer I will accept it.